# confused in echo mysql result inside echo

Tags: php, mysql, echo

after sign in and redirect to next page, i check the user with `$_SESSION`.
Then if username valid, i want to show dropdown list which the list is get from database. I am confuse how to `echo`.

```
    <?php
    session_start(); //Start the session
    if(!isset($_SESSION['pic']))
    {
       header('Location:index.php?p=signin');
    }
    else {
       echo '<div class="form-group">
             <label for="symcat" class="control-label">Symptom Category</label>
             <select id="symcat" name="symcat" class="selectlist form-control">
             <option value=""></option>
             $sql='SELECT category FROM sym_category';
             if ($sql) {
                $res=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) or die(_ERROR26.': '.mysqli_connect_error());
             }
             while ($dat = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                echo '\t<option value="'.$dat[0].'">'.$dat[0].'</option>\n';
             }
             mysqli_free_result($res);
             </select>
             </div> <!-- /form-group -->';
}
?>
```

Comment: So you just want to use another `echo` statement within the 'outer' one? Btw: Why are you eching tons of `\t`? The HTML won't care if it is properly intended.

Comment: this is really bad design though. Why don't you have a view file for this?. Then add the html separately in there. With a simple include, you get your dropdown

Comment: _“I am confuse how to echo”_ – in situations like this: Best not use echo at all. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php And you should not have SQL queries or other data gathering/manipulation in there either - do that first. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model

Comment: With or without view file there are some syntax errors with strings, clearly visible here because of the syntax highlightnig.

Comment: @TobiasF. i am just need an advise to show the option value. eventhough i have echo at the beginning.

Comment: @Akintunde did you mean i call header like the first statement?

Comment: THe answer below should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Akintunde & SheperOfFire said the nice and tidy way is like :

```
<?php
session_start(); //Start the session
if(!isset($_SESSION['pic']))
{
   header('Location:index.php?p=signin');
}
else {
   header('Location:index.php?p=forminputcar');
   }
?>
```

Because, inside of `forminputcar` has `php tag` and `echo` also. Or you can also put above script at the top of `forminputcar` page. So, if session match we stay on current page.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['pic']))
{
   header('charset=UTF-8');
}
else {
   header('Location:index.php?p=signin');
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be better:

```
<?php
    session_start(); //Start the session
    if(!isset($_SESSION['pic']))
    {
       header('Location:index.php?p=signin');
    }
    else {
        $sql = 'SELECT category FROM sym_category';
        if ($sql) {
            $res = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) or die(_ERROR26.': '.mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="symcat" class="control-label">Symptom Category</label>
            <select id="symcat" name="symcat" class="selectlist form-control">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php if (isset($res)): ?>
                    <?php while ($dat = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_NUM)): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $dat[0] ?>"><?php echo $dat[0] ?></option>
                    <?php endwhile ?>
                    <?php mysqli_free_result($res); ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            </select>
        </div> <!-- /form-group -->
<?php } ?>
```

Honestly I still don't think this is a very nice way. If possible, please use view files.
I think it's reasonable to say that you shouldn't use an echo within another echo. [Echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is used to print something to your screen, so it shouldn't be necessary to use an echo within that same echo.

Comment: thanks, after you show me the script. I think my script become untidy. Better I need to use view files.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample code. Maybe it'll help you.

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Fetch the option list details from DB
$optionList = array();
$sql = "SELECT category FROM sym_category";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {         
        $optionList[] = $row['category']
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

// Create the dropdown list
echo "<div class='form-group'>";
    echo '<label for="symcat" class="control-label">Symptom Category</label>';
        echo '<select id="symcat" name="symcat" class="selectlist form-control">';
            echo '<option value=""></option>';
            foreach ($optionList as $key => $value)
            {
                echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";
            }
        echo '</select>';
    echo '</label>';
echo "</div>"
```